# How to move this image 2 pixels down? Syntax reccommendation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an image that I am trying to move down by two pixels. This seems easy enough but I can't quite get the syntax right. Below is the code for my image.

```
= link_to("...with <img src='#{widget_logo_url}' border=0/>   
  Code", "http://website.net", :target => "_blank", :style => "margin-right:11px;")
```

I've tried a few variations to move this image but it doesn't work. Here is what I've tried:

```
= link_to("...with <img src='#{widget_logo_url}' border=0 margin-bottom:-2px/>   
  Code", "http://website.net", :target => "_blank", :style => "margin-right:11px;")

 = link_to("...with <img src='#{widget_logo_url}' border=0 "margin-bottom:-2px">   
  Code", "http://website.net", :target => "_blank", :style => "margin-right:11px;")

 = link_to("...with <img src='#{widget_logo_url}' border=0 margin-bottom:"-2px">   
  Code", "http://website.net", :target => "_blank", :style => "margin-right:11px;")
```

I've looked into the link_to parameters and I tried modifying the :style tag but it moves the entire link as a whole. Some help would be great because I'd really like to move on from this. Thanks.

Comment: Try block version of `link_to` (which is shown in the docs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to), you might be able to do something like :

```
link_to "http://website.net", {:target => "_blank", :style => "margin-right:11px;"} do
  # place here your <img> tag, or whatever you want wrapping up by your link
end
```